# Filtering Json data based on key and assiging the value to state in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

I'm trying to hit the backend call and I get the below JSON data. I've to filter based the key which value starts with "CD_".

After that I've to assign "CD_type" and "CD_name" to two different state from which I'll iterate and show the "name" value in two dropdowns.

JSON

```
   var data = {
        "color": "red",
        "value": "#f00",
        "response": [{
                "code": "CD_type",
                "name": "sampleText_1"
            },
            {
                "code": "RS_type",
                "name": "sampleText_1"
            },
            {
                "code": "AD_name",
                "name": "sampleText_1"
            },
            {
                "code": "RS_type",
                "name": "sampleText_1"
            },
            {
                "code": "AD_name",
                "name": "sampleText_1"
            },
            {
                "code": "CD_name",
                "name": "sampleText_1"
            }, {
                "code": "CD_name",
                "name": "sampleText_1"
            },
            {
                "code": "RS_type",
                "name": "sampleText_1"
            },
            {
                "code": "AD_name",
                "name": "sampleText_1"
            },
            {
                "code": "CD_type",
                "name": "sampleText_2"
            },
            {
                "code": "CD_type",
                "name": "sampleText_3"
            }, {
                "code": "CD_name",
                "name": "sampleText_2"
            },
            {
                "code": "RS_type",
                "name": "sampleText_1"
            },
            {
                "code": "AD_name",
                "name": "sampleText_1"
            },
            {
                "code": "CD_name",
                "name": "sampleText_1"
            },
            {
                "code": "CD_name",
                "name": "sampleText_1"
            },
            {
                "code": "CD_type",
                "name": "sampleText_4"
            },
            {
                "code": "CD_name",
                "name": "sampleText_3"
            },
            {
                "code": "CD_type",
                "name": "sampleText_5"
            }
        ]
}
```

JS:

```
const [cdValue,setCdValue] = useState([]);

const data = data.filter(item => {
   setCdValue(item.code.startsWith("CD_"))
  return item.code.startsWith("CD_")
});
```

Its throwing promise is waiting when I consoled.

Comment: Why are you calling `setCdValue` inside of your `.filter()` callback ?

Comment: @trixn, I was trying to set the value to that state as the return was showing promise pending

Comment: Okay, but `.startsWith()` returns a `boolean` and `setCdValue` will be called for every item in `data`. So you are basically calling `setCdValue` for every item in `data` and the result will simply be `true` or `false` in your state depending on if the last item starts with `CD_`.

Comment: Can you show us the code how you retrieved the data?  I think the `data` you have is the promise object.

Comment: @waterloos, I used promise function as its a api call and the res was this above json.

Comment: I need more detailed code to nail down the problem as well as the exact console output if it is something to do with the asynchronous code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first filter the items. The result is a filtered list of items. And only after that call `setCdValue` with that filtered list:

```
setCdValue(data.filter(item => item.code.startsWith("CD_")));
```

Comment: It worked. One question, you mentioned that startswith returns boolean value, but here when we filter inside the state how its assigning the whole object which has the value?

Comment: @HemaNandagopal What you have is a list of items and what you want is to update the react state with a list of items that meet a certain criterium. `.filter()` will call the function provided with every item and return a list where that function returns `true` for the item. This resulting list is what you want to have in your state. So filter first and then call `setCdValue` **once** with the resulting list. `data.filter()` will return that list.